# place the text when we click the more button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i write the following ,for displaying the text,when i click the more link,it has to show the remaining paragraph .i already tried,but i dont know why its not working,can any help to get of this .

this is my following code

```
    <style>
    p span {
        display:none;
    }

</style>

<script type="javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});

</script>


<table cellpadding:0px;cellspacing:0px;border=0px; width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="width:20%"><a><button class="choosesub_but comingsoon"> list</button></a></td>

<td style="width:47%;"><p style="font:13px verdana;">A written work—be it an essay or a story—is about an idea or concept. An essay explains it; a story narrates it.<a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline;">More...</a>
<span>all to entertain the reader. All paragraphs support each other, leading the reader from the first idea to the final resolution of the written piece of work.</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:30%;"><ul class="choosesub_ul"><li><a href="#">Community event</a></li></ul></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

when i click the more link,it has to display the output as

A written work—be it an essay or a story—is about an idea or concept. An essay explains it; a story narrates it.More...all to entertain the reader. All paragraphs support each other, leading the reader from the first idea to the final resolution of the written piece of work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).next().show();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

You can't bind to the links click event if the link hasn't loaded yet. So we put that code in the `document.ready` block so it executes after everything has loaded.

Also the script type should be `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Then something else that you're not showing us is causing the issue. http://jsbin.com/otojor

Comment: @kanya then it's something else with your code. Code that you're not showing us. Given what you have provided, this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

        $('a').on('click',function () {
            alert("123");
            $(this).siblings().show()
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @kanya you're not being very clear. Not clear at all actually. Both solutions work. When you implement them, they don't work. Show us the rest of your code. "doesn't work" isn't enough to help you.